# Ubuntu 20.04 first boot onto Raspberry Pi 3 A+ drops into U-Boot> shell

Tags: boot, server, raspberrypi

My first attempt at installing Ubuntu 20.04 onto a Raspberry Pi 3 A+ has stalled unexpectedly.

I'm following the process described [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview). I'm using Raspberry Pi Imager for MacOS to create a  boot image from ubuntu-20.04.2-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz onto a 64GB micro-SD card. The card verifies and read/writes OK from MacOS as an external volume called "system-boot".

From MacOS I edited the network-config file on the card to add my Wifi.

The RPi is mounted on a Bittle Robot Dog (serial connection to Arduino compatible board), with HDMI, power, USB keyboard and mouse connected.

Transferring the card to the RPi, and booting produces:

```
Net: No ethernet found.
starting USB...
Bus usb@7e980000: USB DWC2
scanning bus usb@7e980000 for devices... 5 USB Device(s) found
scanning usb for storage devices... 0 Storage Device(s) found
Hit any key to stop autoboot: 0
U-Boot>
```

Boot sequence stops at the above point, leaving the machine in a U-Boot> shell.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnecting the serial connection to the Bittle Nyboard allowed the boot to finish normally. Not sure why?

Edit: Suspect it's related to the RPi use of the serial port https://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection

Answer (score 1):

same issue with https://www.dexterindustries.com/grovepi/

it seems that some add-on devices are preventing it from boot.
Maybe related to undervoltage?

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151